# Retrieving raster data by geographic location using Landsat and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, qgis, epsg, landsat

The project I am working on requires that I retrieve Landsat raster data at specific geographic (lon/lat) locations.  After sifting through some tutorials and experimenting with GDAL, PostGIS, and QGIS, I successfully imported a GeoTIFF Landsat image into a PostGIS raster table and accessed values by geographic location from that table.  However, there were a few issues in the result:

- I do not understand the coordinate system being used by QGIS in its interface, as they range in the hundred thousands
- The raster loaded into QGIS off the coast of Spain, rather than on top of Maine, USA as it was supposed to.

Here's some information about my process. I am fairly new to GIS in general, so I am almost certain theres a blatant error to be found here:

- Download Landsat 8 GeoTIFF file from USGS GloVis
- Rename the band 5 image to something more friendly to command ninja with.
- Create postgres database for raster tables and run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
- Run `gdalinfo LSSampleB5.TIF`, printing the following output:

  `Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
  Files: LSSampleB5Test2.TIF
  Size is 7871, 7971
  Coordinate System is:
  PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 19N",
      GEOGCS["WGS 84",
          DATUM["WGS_1984",
              SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                  AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
          PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
          UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
      PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
      PARAMETER["central_meridian",-69],
      PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
      PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
      PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
      UNIT["metre",1,
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
      AXIS["Easting",EAST],
      AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","32619"]]
  Origin = (318285.000000000000000,5216715.000000000000000)
  Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
  Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Point
  Image Structure Metadata:
    INTERLEAVE=BAND
  Corner Coordinates:
  Upper Left  (  318285.000, 5216715.000) ( 71d23'37.53"W, 47d 4'44.12"N)
  Lower Left  (  318285.000, 4977585.000) ( 71d18' 9.77"W, 44d55'42.53"N)
  Upper Right (  554415.000, 5216715.000) ( 68d16'58.41"W, 47d 6' 6.11"N)
  Lower Right (  554415.000, 4977585.000) ( 68d18'36.69"W, 44d56'58.62"N)
  Center      (  436350.000, 5097150.000) ( 69d49'20.56"W, 46d 1'29.87"N)
  Band 1 Block=7871x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray`
- I interpretted this output as EPSG 4326 format (which may be my crime), so I ran the following command to import the GeoTIFF as a PostGIS raster:

  `raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I LSSampleB5.TIF -F -t 50x50 -d | psql -U postgres rastertest`
- This successfully imported a new table.  I then used QGIS to get a visual intuition of what was going on.
- Under `Database -> DB Manager -> PostGIS -> rastertest -> public` I added my lssampleb5 to the canvas.
- I created a new XYZ Connection in QGIS to add Google satillite hybrid images for reference.  The url I used was `https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}` with min and max zoom of 0 and 19 respectively.
- Here is where I took note of the fact that the lssample layer landed off the coast of Spain on the Google Hybrid map.
- I made sure both layers were on EPSG 4326 projection, no change.
- Not too discouraged to move on, I tried a database query to get a single pixel value.  Since my sample data landed near Spain, I used QGIS to sample a valid coordinate pair near there for the query.  The query was:

  `SELECT  rid, ST_Value(rast, 1, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(448956,5041439), 4326)) as b5
  FROM lssampleb5
  WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(448956,5041439), 4326)::geometry, 1);`
- This returned a valid row ID and an ST_VALUE of 5776.  Trying coordinates outside the range displayed by QGIS resulted in no returned entries, which isn't unexpected.

So, first of all, I do not know what QGIS is using for its coordinate system.  It's definitely not longitude and latitude in a raw form, but from my understanding, EPSG 4326 is supposed to be a geographic projection.

Second, I don't know why QGIS is misplacing the Landsat scene in the wrong place, or where in the process the scene was not transformed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join us at [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), that´s the place for GIS related Q/A!
To help you out here:

- Indeed, your crime was the CRS. The top level `PROJCRS` tag is the
  key here, it reads out `"WGS 84 / UTM zone 19N"` from the data, with
  the EPSG reference at the bottom (`AUTHORITY["EPSG","32619"]]`).
  [EPSG:32619](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-19n/) is a [UTM projected CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) based on the WGS84 geoid (datum) and with units in meter, defined as the projected distance to the corresponding reference meridians (Easting) and the equator (Northing). Since you defined the wrong CRS during import (i.e. EPSG:4326), the inherent coordinate values of the raster were treated as degree´s and the whole thing placed to the other end of the world. Run [UpdateRasterSRID](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_UpdateRasterSRID.html) (`SELECT UpdateRasterSRID(<shema_name>, <your_raster_table>, rast, 32619);`) to set the raster's metadata to the correct CRS and reload the layer.
- As for QGIS: it uses the CRS that you tell it to use. QGIS comes with a very handy *on-the-fly* reprojection feature (*OTF*, check out the general man page on 'working with projections' [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html)) that lets you define an arbitrary CRS for your data to be projected and displayed (i.e. it reprojects the data's CRS into the defined one in memory, the data's metadata stays untouched).
  You can find the quick link button to the *OTF* settings in the bottom right corner of the GUI; set it to your desired SRID (e.g. 4326) (you´ll notice how the visual representation of your data changes according to the chosen projection. also the displayed coordinates will use the CRS units, e.g. decimal degrees for WGS84).

Comment: I dare say that was the most straightforward and informative answer I've ever gotten on this site. Thank you! It's amazing how much supposed "tutorials" miss for just raw information.  I upvoted, but I don't have the reputation for it to show yet, sorry.

Comment: @user76987 bam, such praise...thanks. working with projections is rather complex and out of scope for most tutorials I guess. If you got the time, try digging into some meta info on how transformations work (not necessarily the mathematical aspects, more the why and how). it will help you *a lot* for your work with geospatial data. as for the upvote: consider accepting the answer if you think it helped you (it is recommended to wait 24h though, so that others might come and add answers)

Comment: Yes, I was waiting to accept the answer until after I tried the update query and reloaded my QGIS project.  It appears to have worked great, so I'll accept the answer in a bit to give a chance for others input as you said.  As far as I'm concerned though, problem solved.